# Python plotting time versus packets based on csv file

Tags: python, csv, graph, numpy, matplotlib

I have a bunch of data in a text file like this:

```
99150, 2012-05-18 14:30:08.592276
100350, 2012-05-18 14:31:09.093357
97710, 2012-05-18 14:32:09.583485
94980, 2012-05-18 14:33:10.047794
95670, 2012-05-18 14:34:10.559798
97170, 2012-05-18 14:35:11.073576
98850, 2012-05-18 14:36:11.562930
98280, 2012-05-18 14:37:12.058591
97950, 2012-05-18 14:38:12.547585
102510, 2012-05-18 14:39:13.053431
```

I want to make a simple plot of it and output the image. I've started with the following:

```
#!/bin/python

import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

filename="pps_counter.log"

def getColumn(filename, column):
    results = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=",")
    return [result[column] for result in results]

time = getColumn(filename,1)
packets = getColumn(filename,0)

plt.figure("Packets Per Minute")
plt.xlabel("Time(minutes)")
plt.ylabel("Number of Packets")
plt.plot(time,packets)
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plotter.py", line 16, in <module>
    time = getColumn(filename,1)
  File "plotter.py", line 14, in getColumn
    return [result[column] for result in results]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [csv2rec](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec) (or genfromtxt with a converter function). This will convert the times to python datetimes which you can plot with `matplotlib`.

```
from matplotlib.mlab import csv2rec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

data = csv2rec('pps_counter.log', names=['packets', 'time'])

plt.plot_date(data['time'], data['packets'])
plt.xlabel("Time(minutes)")
plt.ylabel("Number of Packets")
plt.title("Packets Per Minute")

plt.show()
```

Comment: awesome! thanks, I've already customized the graph and set it to output to a file... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some error checking
like

```
return [ result[column] if column < len( result ) else None for result in results]
```

it looks like there is a line in your file that is missing a `,`

Comment: Or it could be a blank line at the end; that causes the same error.

Comment: I added the error checking that @corn3lius suggested but I also tried the old approach and removed the trailing blank line in the file, both result in:   File "plotter.py", line 21, in <module>
    plt.figure("Packets Per Minute")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 257, in figure
    num = int(num)  # crude validation of num argument

Comment: I used the None (null) object as the error case you can use 0 or something noticeable in your graph. or you could find and remove the line(s) in your input.